# cx_oracle вызов процедуры

Tags: python, oracle

Есть процедура:

```
PROCEDURE create_pkg_header(p_import_id IN NUMBER,
                           p_lm_user   IN NUMBER,
                           p_data      IN qifc_import_items.data%TYPE)
```

`data` в `qifc_import_items` - строка примерно с таким содержимым: `PH|26934|N|N|N|N|`.

Вызываю процедуру след. образом:

```
dta = "PH|26934|N|N|N|N|"
oracle_str_header = """
     begin
             QGUARADM.QIFCP_PACKAGE_CUSTOM.CREATE_PKG_HEADER(
              p_import_id => 900,
              p_lm_user => 6,
              p_data =>\'%s\'
             );
             end;
    """ % dta
 cursor.execute(oracle_str_header)
```

При вызове выдаёт ошибку:

> ORA-20101:BEX_QIFCP_PACKAGE_CUSTOM_REQU_PARAM_NOT_SET

при том, что вроде же все параметры процедуры установлены.

Как исправить?

UPD

```
parms = [900, 6, dta]
cursor.callproc("QGUARADM.QIFCP_PACKAGE_CUSTOM.CREATE_PKG_HEADER", parms)
```

вызывает, к сожалению, такую же ошибку.
При передаче параметров таким образом:

```
parms_kw = dict(p_import_id=900, p_lm_user=6, p_data=dta)
```

получается следующая ошибка:

> function takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Скорее всего эта ошибка явно выбрасывается где-то в коде процедуры. Ищите в ней текст `raise ...`. Если хотите чтобы Вам можно было дать ответ опубликуйте [минимальный пример, на котором можно воспроизвести ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться методом [`cursor.callproc()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.callproc):

```
parms = [900, 6, dta]
cursor.callproc("QGUARADM.QIFCP_PACKAGE_CUSTOM.CREATE_PKG_HEADER", parms)
```

или так:

```
parms_kw = dict(p_import_id=900, p_lm_user=6, p_data=dta)
cursor.callproc("QGUARADM.QIFCP_PACKAGE_CUSTOM.CREATE_PKG_HEADER", **parms_kw)
```