# Как создать хранимую процедуру в скрипте?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

Ищу способ создать хранимую процедуру в Python скрипте.

Знаю, что `cursor.callproc` в модуле `cx_oracle` предназначена для вызова существующей хранимой процедуры, как например [в этом топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918409/217579).

А какой есть способ/метод **создания** хранимой процедуры?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Create Oracle stored procedure in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64000401) от участника [@narayana kandukuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10544237/narayana-kandukuri)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64000401

Answer (score 2):

Просто вызывайте [`execute()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#) с SQL предложением [`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-PROCEDURE.html#GUID-771879D8-BBFD-4D87-8A6C-290102142DA3).

Чтобы проверить, скомпилировалась ли процедура, надо запросом проверить наличие ошибок в представлении `user_errors`:

```
from cx_Oracle import connect 

conn = connect ('<connect string>', encoding="utf-8")
with conn.cursor () as cursor:
    cursor.execute ("""create or replace procedure x (a in number) as begin BLAH end;""")
    cursor.execute ("""
        select name, type, line, position, text
        from user_errors
        where name = 'X'
        order by name, type, line, position""")
    rows = cursor.fetchall ()
    print (rows)
```

Вывод:

```
[('X', 'PROCEDURE', 1, 41, 
'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
\n\n   := . ( @ % ;\nThe symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.\n')]
```

Мы уже работаем над тем, как в будущих версиях *cx_Oracle* напрямую обрабатывать флаг `success with info` и   сообщения об ошибках компиляции.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64001225) от участника [@Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones)</sub>